# Yoast taking over my Wordpress title tag

Tags: loop, title, seo, plugin-wp-seo-yoast

I have this code:

```
 <h1><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
```

That is meant to display the title of my blog post only. But because Yoast has a SEO title of something else, it is displaying that title on the page instead of `the_title()` eg:

It should be:

**This is a title**

And not what Yoast is doing:

**This is a title - my site name**

Comment: That's not what the SEO title does/is for. Are you sure you haven't used `wp_title()` in your template by mistake?

Comment: Ah, yeah. I was pulling in the wrong template which was wp_title(). Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not what the SEO title does/is for. It appears that you've used the [`wp_title()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/wp_title/) function in your template by mistake.

`wp_title()` is intended for use in the `<title>` tag in the `<head>` for setting the browser tab/document title. However, since WordPress 4.1 this has been superseded (but not officially *deprecated*, yet) by [`add_theme_support( 'title-tag' )`](https://make.wordpress.org/core/2014/10/29/title-tags-in-4-1/), so these days `wp_title()` really shouldn't be used.